# change color of javafx datepicker based on dates count from database

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, javafx

For example : I have extracted the dates from my databases and get this using algorithm which tell me no of occurrences of each date.

{2018-11-30=2, 2018-11-28=1, 2018-12-12=3, 2018-11-24=2, 2018-11-23=5, 2018-12-05=1, 2019-11-05=1, 2018-12-04=2, 2018-12-03=1, 2018-12-02=1, 2018-12-01=1}

Now I want to have color on datepicker cell based on dates count from data above
Eg:-

```
if (2018-11-30 >1){
setStyle("-fx-background-color: #008000;");
}else if (2018-11-30 == 1 ){
setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
}else{
setStyle("-fx-background-color: #white;");
}
```

The code I have is below. But I don't know how to convert this as above code

```
public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);



                if (MonthDay.from(item).equals(MonthDay.of(11, 25)) && !(getStyleClass().contains("next-month")
                        || getStyleClass().contains("previous-month"))) {
                    setTooltip(new Tooltip("Only Morning left"));
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFF00;");
                } else if (item.equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1))) {
                    setTooltip(new Tooltip("Only Evening Left"));
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #008000;");

                } else if (item.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                    setTooltip(new Tooltip("Both booked"));
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF0000;");
                } else {

                }


            }
```

Comment: Please post [mcve]. To avoid database dependency hard code the test data.

Comment: I have edited...plz have a look

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;) Then how comes that you don't provide the example as suggested ... tsss